# Adode UXP Alchemist- sorceror plugin permission error

Tags: java, react-native, jsx

Need some help here I have been using the Alchemist- sorcerer Plugin where I get an error when I try to load my plugin created via sorcerer.

```
{
   "manifestVersion": 5,
   "name": "Table Runner",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "id": "table runner",
   "main": "index.html",
   "requiredPermissions": {
      "launchProcess": "request"
   },
```

This is the manifest code generated by my sorcerer-alchemist plugin creator
I have used the Alchemist - sorcerer plugin creator

But when i try to import it on my adobe UXP developer tool It throws an errror.

```
Plugin Load Failed.
Devtools: Plugin table runner : Expected an object for the permission 'launchProcess'
```

Please let me know what should i do